# Hapi.js Documentation generator for REST API Servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, hapi.js

I was looking for a tool that generates static documentation for Hapi.js routes, but doesn't create dependencies to the API server.

So I was just visualising a cli tool where I could pass my `server.js` as an argument, and would create the API documentation by parsing my route definitions.

`hapi-swagger` modules fails, as it creates the follwoing dependencies to my server;

- Have to define a view engine
- Have to disable the minimal option of my api servers
- Have to define a /documentation route (I know I can change that, but the issue persists)

If such tool doesn't exists, what is the best alternative to create swagger ui static files documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: They have module named lout.. But its deprecated now.. You can also create own module to do that . mention here.. Me too interested in this

Comment: @Sathish Where do you see lout is deprecated?

Comment: @Sathish lout also does the same, it binds to the server as an endpoint and generates them dynamically.

Comment: It seems that's much doable to create a module on my own by using the [`server.table()`](http://hapijs.com/api#servertablehost).

Comment: @gergo it seems there is no active development on that module

Comment: @Sathish What issues does it have? If it works, then it works. I don't think it is deprecated.

Comment: @Evalon can conditionally load API documentation plugins depending on the environment. That way they only exist for development and not for production, etc. Would that work?

Comment: @KevinWu That's not a bad idea actually, but still it doesn't serve my purpose of serving the documentation as static files from an other web server. What if I want to expose them as public documentation?

Answer (score 0):

First the lout module is officially supported by hapijs and is not deprecated. It provides an alternative to swagger. But it does not solve your problem because it does not generate static html/css.

Now to the solution: I would add hapi-swagger but only in development like this (so you keep your server lightweight in staging/production)...

```
...
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
   //Register inert, vision, hapi-swagger with server.register()
}
...
```

...then use [bootprint-swagger](https://github.com/nknapp/bootprint-swagger#overview) or something similar to generate static html which you can serve on a web server of your choice.

Hope this helps.